# Snap SVG - Animating a Path in the opposite direction

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I am working on a path animation, but am stuck at how to accomplish it in reverse.

http://jsfiddle.net/t1yu3mcn/1/

Currently, the red path starts at full length, and over time becomes shorter and shorter **from the right direction**. I want to accomplish the same animation but where the path gets shorter **starting from the left** direction. (starts disappearing from the left rectangle, and ends disappearing at the right rectangle).

I have tried altering the following snippet inside .animate:

```
'stroke-dasharray':  val + ' ' + (pathCoverLength - val)
```

But changing this around to different values never results in the correct effect.

Does anybody know an easy way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to juggle the dashOffset point further...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t1yu3mcn/2/)

```
pathCover.attr({ strokeDasharray: pathCoverLength + ' ' + pathCoverLength })

Snap.animate(pathCoverLength*2, pathCoverLength, function(val) {
    pathCover.attr({
        strokeDashoffset: val  });
}, 7000, mina.ease);
```